# What "font type" are the 14 standard PDF fonts?

Tags: pdf, fonts

The [pdf 1.7 reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) mentions that there are 14 Fonts that do not require embedding.

> PDF prescribes a set of 14 standard fonts that can be used without
>   prior definition. These include four faces each of three Latin text
>   typefaces (Courier, Helvetica*, and Times*), as well as two symbolic
>   fonts (Symbol and ITC Zapf Dingbats ® ). These fonts, or suitable
>   substitute fonts with the same metrics, are required to be available
>   in all PDF consumer applications

The same reference document additionally enumerates different "font types" defined in PDF (`/Subtype` being `/Type0`,`/Type1`,`/Type3`,`/CIDFontType0`,`/CIDFontType2`,`/MMType1`,`/TrueType`).

The problem, and hence reason for this question, is that the font type, has implications to the way the `text string data` is mapped to the corresponding `glyphs` of the font. The reference documents broadly categorizes "*simple*" and "*composite*" fonts. Only "*composite*" fonts are described as being able to have an multi-byte character encoding. The "*simple*" font types, are basically encoded via single byte `1byte = 1glyph`.

It would be hence really interesteting to know if the 14 base /standard fonts, are supposedly simple fonts, or if they can be used as as CID-keyed fonts? 
Or plainly, what "font type" are those 14 standard fonts?.

The already linked reference lists the following font types

> - Type0 (PDF 1.2) A composite font—a font composed of glyphs from a descendant CIDFont (see Section 5.6, “Composite Fonts”)
> - Type 1 Type1 A font that defines glyph shapes using Type 1 font technology (see Section 5.5.1, “Type 1 Fonts”).
> - MMType1 A multiple master font an extension of the Type 1 font that allows the generation of a wide variety of typeface styles from a
>     single font (see “Multiple Master Fonts” on page 416)
> - Type 3 Type3 A font that defines glyphs with streams of PDF graphics operators (see Section 5.5.4, “Type 3 Fonts”)
> - TrueType TrueType A font based on the TrueType font format (see Section 5.5.2, “TrueType Fonts”)
> - CIDFont CIDFontType0 (PDF 1.2) A CIDFont whose glyph descriptions are based on Type 1 font technology (see Section 5.6.3, “CIDFonts”)
> - CIDFontType2 (PDF 1.2) A CIDFont whose glyph descriptions are based on TrueType font technology (see Section 5.6.3, “CIDFonts”)

Answer (score 2):

The standard 14 PDF fonts are `Type1` fonts. The AFM files needed to get the necessary meta information like glyph width can be obtained freely from Adobe. As for the encoding: Most applications use `MacRomanEncoding` or `WinAnsiEncoding`.

Comment: *"Most applications use MacRomanEncoding or WinAnsiEncoding."* - for the simple reason that pdf viewers essentially only need to bring along the characters of the named encodings.

Comment: @mkl would that mean that [without embedding a font, assuming it is possible to display even only the 4281 glyphs of the AGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57295834/1711186) cannot be seen as something most pdf viewers will guarantee?

Comment: @gettalong I though as much, but since I was adviced on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57295834/1711186), that it would be possible to use *predefined CJK CMaps*, does this mean that most CJK glyphs are available in `/Type1` fonts?

Comment: @mkl It would be great if you'd help me point me to the resource from which you have gathered that information, i.e. what pdf viewers are supposed to provide (in terms of supported fonts, and glyphs, and characters sets)

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I don't think that CJK glyphs would be available as `/Type1` fonts but only as composite fonts. As for the standard 14 PDF fonts, maybe this helps: In [this PDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/examples/standard_pdf_fonts.pdf) you will find all available glyphs defined by the AFM files (the first batch shows all glyphs for the `WinAnsiEncoding` or the built-in encoding, below are the remaining glyphs).

Comment: @humanityANDpeace See the section "Which fonts does a viewer have to have available?" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464299/1729265).